# Paged virtual address translation using a linear page table

Tags: operating-system, paging, virtual-memory

I have trouble doing this small exercise: [image]

So far I got this:
For VADDR = `0x5ddb`, binary representation is `0101 1101 1101 1011`, thus we know the `VPN = 101 = 5`.

What's the next step?

Answer (score 2):

The most significant three bits constitute the virtual page number, the remaining twelve bits form the offset into the page frame.
In your concrete example the virtual page number is `5`, as you correctly mentioned, and the offset is

```
1101 1101 1011 = 0xddb = 3547
```

Now proceed like this:

1. Use the *virtual page number* as an index into the page table. The 5<sup>th</sup> (starting from zero) is `0x80000006`.
2. Check the *validity bit*. It's set, so the page entry is valid. If it was **not** the page would not be in memory and a *page fault* would occur.
3. As said in the image, the rest of the entry is the *page frame number*. It's the 6<sup>th</sup> page frame, so you can calculate the page frame's phyiscal address by multiplying this number with the size of a page frame, that is, 4 KiB. Hence, the physical address is

   ```
   6 * 4 KiB = 24 KiB = 24576
   ```
4. Add the offset to the physical address of the page frame:

   ```
   24576 + 3547 = 28123
   ```

   And you have your address.

**The virtual address `0x5ddb` corresponds to the physical address `28123 = 0x6ddb` on the described system.**